# How to get vmware vm list which has more than 25% of used space of the particular datastore using powershell?

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I need to get vm list which has 25% of the used space in the particular datastore.

```
$vmdatastore = Get-Datastore "XXXXX-LUN001" | select Name, @{N = Capacity";E={[math]::Round($_.ExtensionData.Summary.Capacity / 1GB, 2)}},@{N="FreeSpace";E={[math]::Round($_.ExtensionData.Summary.FreeSpace/1GB, 2)}}, @{N="PercentageFreeSpace";E={[math]::Round(($_.FreeSpaceGB)  /($_.CapacityGB) * 100, 2)}} 

$vmlists=Get-Datastore "XXXXX-LUN001" | Get-VM | Select name, @{N="DSName";E={$vmdatastore.Name}},usedspacegb,  provisionedspacegb
```

Help me to get vm list which has 25% of used space in the particular datastore..
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Do you mean 25% of the space allocated to it in the datastore, or 25% of the entire datastore?

Comment: I need migrate list of VM which is 25% space allocated to it in the datastore to another datastore. in order to free up space in the source datastore @Spencer

Comment: help me to solve this.. much time would be save for me @Spencer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure, if that is what you want, but if you want a list of VMs that together take up at least 25% of the capacity of your datastore, this approach might help:

```
$ds = Get-Datastore "XXXXX-LUN001"
$dsVMs = Get-VM -Datastore $ds
$vmUsedSpace = 0
$vmMigrationCandidates = @()
$dsCapacityThreshold = $ds.CapacityGB / 4

while ($vmUsedSpace -le $dsCapacityThreshold -and $dsVMs.Count -gt 0)
{
    $vm,$dsVMs = $dsVMs
    $vmUsedSpace += $vm.UsedSpaceGB
    $vmMigrationCandidates += $vm
}
```

`$vmMigrationCandidates` will hold a list of VMs that together use up at least 25% of the datastores total capacity. (Or all vms on this datastore, if they together dont reach the threshold.)

You still need to decide, if you prefer to migrate a few "big" vms instead of many "small" ones. Also take into account, that there might be DRS host- or vm-affinity rules that you have to take into account.

Comment: Thanks @manuel.. it seem like it working fine.. One doubt in that is

$dsCapacityThreshold = $ds.CapacityGB / 4. what is 4 in this? whether it is 40% or something else?

Comment: Total capacity / 4 gives you a 1/4 which is 25%

Answer (score 0):

```
$gt25 = $vmdatastore | ?{$_.PercentageFreeSpace -gt 25}
Get-Datastore -name $gt25 | Get-VM
```

After comment... how about

```
 $vmdatastore =  Get-Datastore "xxxxyourdatastorexxx" | select Name, @{N = 
 "Capacity";E={[math]::Round($_.ExtensionData.Summ
  ary.Capacity / 1GB, 2)}}, @{N = "QuarterOfThat";E= 
 {[math]::Round($_.ExtensionData.Summary.Capacity / 1GB / 4, 2)}}

 $vmlist = Get-Datastore ABN_NP_CORE2 | get-vm | ? {$_.usedspaceGB -gt 
 $vmdatastore.QuarterOfThat}


 $vmlist.usedspaceGB
```

Comment: Or add to first line | ? {$_.PercentageFreeSpace -gt "25"}

Comment: i need vm list which is allocated to 25% of the datastore space.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, best update the question with an example list.

Comment: I need to free up 25% of the datastore size.. so i am in need to migrate 25% of vm space allocated in that datastore.. understand?